# How to speed up transferring column values from a pandas dataframe to another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe such as:

[image]

And after a complex process I want a dataframe such as:

[image]

So, I do this:

```
import pandas as pd

def complex_process(value):
    values=value.split(',')
    return ['results for '+x for x in values]

df=pd.DataFrame([['id1','a,b,c'],['id2','d'],['id3','e,f']],columns=['id','value'])

result_list=[]
id_list=[]
value_list=[]
for row in df.itertuples():
    results=complex_process(row.value)
    for result in results:
        result_list.append(result)
        id_list.append(row.id)
        value_list.append(row.value)
df_new=pd.DataFrame()
df_new['id']=id_list
df_new['value']=value_list
df_new['result']=result_list
```

This takes a long time with a large dataset. I tested the complex process and it doesn't take very long. Is there a faster way to transfer the columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing this operation with lists and loops is cumbersome and looping through DataFrames is computationally expensive, but pandas has lots of built-in operations so you shouldn't need to iterate through DataFrames most of the time.

Since your `complex_process` function is intended as a placeholder, let's apply your function to each row using `.apply`, and save the results in a new row called `result`:

```
df['result'] = df.value.apply(complex_process)
```

Your DataFrame will look like this:

```
>>> df
    id  value                                        results
0  id1  a,b,c  [results for a, results for b, results for c]
1  id2      d                                [results for d]
2  id3    e,f                 [results for e, results for f]
```

Now you can use the convenient `.explode` method to expand a list-like column into rows. This will duplicate the other columns and the index, so we can reset the index as well, and drop the old index.

```
df_new = df.explode('result').reset_index(drop=True)
```

Final result:

```
>>> df_new
    id  value         result
0  id1  a,b,c  results for a
1  id1  a,b,c  results for b
2  id1  a,b,c  results for c
3  id2      d  results for d
4  id3    e,f  results for e
5  id3    e,f  results for f
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. My purpose was not to split the string, that was just an example to illustrate that results for each value are coming out of the "complex function." I didn't attach the actual function because it's too long and not relevant, but it does much more than that and needs to be there to create the results. My question is about how to handle the multiple results for each row.

Comment: Okay, that's what I figured might be the case — I think you can apply your function to each row, and then still use `.explode` to handle multiple results for each row. I'll update my answer when I have a moment

Comment: I updated my answer to apply any function `complex_process` rowwise using `.apply`— let me know if this is more what you were looking for

Comment: This is great! Thank you, Derek!

Comment: No problem, if my answer was helpful, please consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) so that people with a similar question are directed to the right answer too. Cheers!